# Amount used heap looking at gcmv in eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, garbage-collection, jvm

It is not clear to me how much memory my app is actually needs when I use Garbage Collection and Memory Visualizer in Eclipse. Looking at this graph:
[image: gcmv view]

At say 0:12 it has acquired a bit more than 0,4 GB. I know it acquires more heap (heap size in graph) than actually needs. But what I want to see is how much memory it really uses. The other two graphs just confuses the picture. Can I do that in gcmv?

Comment: you need to clarify what you mean by "how much it really uses".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no clear answer to the question, how much memory is used, as that depends on the definition of *used*. At some time, the JVM will acquire memory and the application will *use* memory by writing into it to be able to read it at a later time. You can say, it uses the memory, as long as there will be another access to that memory at a later time. If you’re never going to read a value, the memory holding the value is not really needed, but it’s a technical challenge to find out whether the application is going to read it again.

One way to predict whether there will be an access at a later time, is to utilize the object structure and consider every unreachable object as unused. This analysis, called garbage collection, runs at certain points of time, so at these points, we will often find the actually used memory to be smaller than the memory that the application used between two garbage collection runs. But between these points, there is no knowledge about the used memory amount regarding reachable objects.

So you see two graphs in your chart, one representing the memory that your application has written data into between two garbage collection cycles, and the other connects the resulting still-reachable memory after garbage collection. The *required* size is assumed to lie somewhere in-between. For arbitrary time points, the higher “before collection” values stem from the fact that the application has used them without a garbage collection happening, but *if* a garbage collection had happened at that time, the actually used (still reachable) memory is likely to be lower than that, but unlikely to be lower than the “after collection” values (though even that is not known for sure).

When you want to be on the safe side, you ensure that there’s always at least as much memory as the recorded “before collection” value available and the application should just run as in your recorded process. However, you possibly could reduce the available memory to a value between the “before collection” and the maximum “after collection” value and still run the application successfully, but with different garbage collection cycles, possibly spending more CPU time for garbage collection.